# How do I remap the default CTRL+f (find) in Visual Studio Code such that I can use CTRL+f as is typical in unix/linux?

Tags: ide, settings, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

In Visual Studio Code, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> activates the Find widget. I use vscode on Windows 10 (ssh into 'nix) and separately on the Ubuntu 18.04 Linux distro (w/Gnome Shell), when using the integrated terminal. I expected <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to step one character forward in the CLI, as is typical on many Linux terminals, within vscode. How do I accomplish this?

I'd additionally like to maintain the find functionality, if possible, though with a different binding.

Because my search in SO retrieved little, I'm posting the solution and references I found for the community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After searching several links via Google, I found straightforward documentation to solve this problem at https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/integrated-terminal/.

#### The solution, in summary:

1. Open up Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and typing `keyboard` and then `enter` or `return`.
2. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> in the Keyboard Shortcuts search bar and find the "Terminal: Focus Find Widget" line. Mine looks like this:[image: Terminal Focus Keybinding UI]
3. Click the pencil icon to alter the keybinding. One available for me was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>.

*Note: the following is pasted from [the docs](https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/integrated-terminal/) for easy reference.*

Or, in your `keybindings.json` change:

```json
{ "key": "ctrl+f", "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.focusFindWidget",
                      "when": "terminalFocus" },
```

to something like this:

```json
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+f", "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.focusFindWidget",
                      "when": "terminalFocus" },
```

Comment: In my current version of VSCode (v1.51.1), the "Keyboard Preferences" mentioned above is actually "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts".

Comment: Thank you @PengheGeng -- I've updated in the answer and can confirm the same on my 'nix build, version 1.52.0.

Answer (score 4):

I also had to add this to my settings.json to make it work (VSCode version 1.62.0):

```
  "terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [
    "-workbench.action.terminal.focusFind"
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

In my VSCode v1.58.2, it now looks like this:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+f",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusFind",
        "when": "terminalFindFocused && terminalProcessSupported || terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+f",
        "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.focusFind",
        "when": "terminalFindFocused && terminalProcessSupported || terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
    }
]
```